# algorithm for merging polygons by across certain edges

Tags: c#, algorithm, graph, geometry

I have a list of lists of edges of XY points that I would like to merge on certain edges,

A slightly simplified version is this:

```
class XY{
    double X;
    double Y;
    public XY(double x, double y){
       this.X=x;
       this.Y=y;
    }
}

Edge {
    XY p1;
    XY p2;
    bool mergeOn;
}
```

Now I would like to merge these lists/polygons such that all edges that have the mergeOn property disapear. For example: 
[image: two squares seperated by red line]

Would be merged on the redline.

However when doing this I need to retain the order of the points in such a way that a complete polygon can be made out of following each line.

The obvious sollution for this is to loop over the edges that make up a polygon and when you meet a mergeOn edge you switch to the other side however this does not work for a case such as the following:

[[image: it looks great]where merging the two polgons in this manner would result in the lose of the edge in the hole, which should instead become it's own list.

```
List l1= new List<edge>();
l1.add(new Edge(new XY(0,0) , new XY(10,0),false));
l1.add(new Edge(new XY(10,0) , new XY(10,3),true));
l1.add(new Edge(new XY(10,3) , new XY(10,7),false));
l1.add(new Edge(new XY(10,7) , new XY(10,10),true));
l1.add(new Edge(new XY(10,10) , new XY(0,10),false));
l1.add(new Edge(new XY(0,10) , new XY(0,0),false));

l2.add(new Edge(new XY(20,0) , new XY(20,10),false));
l2.add(new Edge(new XY(20,10) , new XY(10,10),false));
l2.add(new Edge(new XY(10,10) , new XY(10,7),true));
l2.add(new Edge(new XY(10,7) , new XY(12,7),false));
l2.add(new Edge(new XY(12,7) , new XY(12,3),false));
l2.add(new Edge(new XY(12,3) , new XY(10,3),false));
l2.add(new Edge(new XY(10,3) , new XY(10,0),true));
l2.add(new Edge(new XY(10,0) , new XY(20,0),true));

merge(new list{l1,l2});
```

which should result in something like this 
list{l3,l4}
with l3 being

```
new Edge(new XY(0,0) , new XY(20,0),false)
new Edge(new XY(20,0) , new XY(20,10),false)
new Edge(new XY(20,10) , new XY(0,10),false)
new Edge(new XY(0,10) , new XY(0,0),false)
```

and l4 being

```
new Edge(new XY(10,3) , new XY(12,3),false)
new Edge(new XY(12,3) , new XY(12,7),false)
new Edge(new XY(12,7) , new XY(10,7),false)
new Edge(new XY(10,7) , new XY(10,3),false)
```

Some notes it's possible that there is more then one [image] and it's also possible for the same point to occur in more then two edges (even with these edges not being mergeOn).

Any idea what type of algoritm might work here?

Note that right now due to some underlying double point precision problems sometimes the edges don't quite match up, while I can solve that myself it does make tools such as the clipperlib less usefull.

After some discussion in chat here are some clarifications: no two lines in the initial data can ever intersect, they can share points though (one point can be in many different lines). The final goal of this method is to use it in a pathfinding solution, the redlines are obstacle lines that this agent can move through while the black lines cannot be moved through (for example the red lines might be a river while the black lines are a large rock, an amphibious vehicle can cross the river but not the rock).

Comment: This seems like an XY problem XD

Comment: Wait the XY problem is about asking how to implement my sollution rather then the sollution to the problem, however in this case I really do have a bunch of polygons that have to be merged with these constraints and the example as ideal output, the only "solution" that I suggest is by looping over the edges but that fails in the second case.

Comment: I know it was a joke, you have a class called XY... its funny

Comment: That is based on the program that uses this, it's checking to see if the current agent is capable of traversing the barrier and if it's then the mergeOn is set to true. This is later used in dealing with a navigation mesh.

Comment: Will lines always be horizontal or vertical?

Comment: No lines can be at any angle, they can even be tesselated circles.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121257/discussion-between-neil-and-thijser).